# How to select data from postgres SQL table

Tags: postgresql

```
group id   gender   count
-------    ------   -----
01          M       10
01          F       5
02          M       6
03          F       2
```

Select data As

```
groupId   Male Female 
-------   ---- -----  
01         10   5
02          6   0
03          0   2
```

Comment: what you tried ? you need to post code and will improve not providing result for your own work.

Comment: You need a pivot table. You can use the [crosstab function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the inline view and join to perform the required action.

You have not mentioned the table name. I have assumed as TableName and written the query. Use the below.

```
select m.groupId as groupId, m.count as Male,f.count as Female from 
(select groupId, gender, count from tablename where gender = 'M')m join (select groupId, gender, count from tablename where gender = 'F')f on m.groupid = f.groupid
```

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that the name of your table is test, so your query could be:

```
 select tab.groupId, sum(CASE WHEN tab.gender = 'M' THEN tab.count ELSE 0 END) as male, sum(CASE WHEN tab.gender = 'F' THEN tab.count ELSE 0 END) as female from test tab group by tab.groupId order by tab.groupId
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way:

```
with the_table(group_id, gender, count) as(
    select 01,'M',10 union all
    select 01,'F',5 union all
    select 02,'M',6 union all
    select 03,'F',2
)

select coalesce(t1.group_id, t2.group_id) as group_id, coalesce(t1.count, 0) as male, coalesce(t2.count, 0) as female
from 
(select group_id, count from the_table where gender = 'M') t1
full join
(select group_id, count from the_table where gender = 'F') t2
on t1.group_id = t2.group_id
```

Side note: `count` is bad choice for column name, it is reserved keyword